# I get a Duplicate Class error when running my Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting a `Duplicate class` error when running my Android project. It is giving the following error:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in
modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21
(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20
(org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20) Duplicate class found
```

My build.gradle code is this:

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    }
    
    apply plugin:'kotlin-parcelize'
    
    android {
        namespace 'com.example.quitanda'
        compileSdk 33
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.quitanda"
            minSdk 21
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables {
                useSupportLibrary true
            }
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '11'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            compose true
        }
        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            resources {
                excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
        implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
        implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
        implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
        implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
        implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
        implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
        androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
        debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
        debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    
        // Minha implementação
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
        //2.6.0-alpha09
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0-beta01"
        //def moshiVersion = "1.10.0"
        //implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiVersion"
    
        implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0-RC1'
        //1.0.0-alpha18
        implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:1.0.0-alpha19"
        //implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.14.0"
        implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.21.3-beta"
        implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2"
        //1.4.2
        implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.3"
        implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
        implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.11.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    }
```

I tried excluding the duplicate classes using the code below:

```
    apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

        }
    }
```

I added the above code, but then I got this error:

```
Plugin with id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' not found
```

When I remove the apply it gives the error:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.21) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
```

[SOLVED]

My solution was to add below command to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     constraints {
         implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
             because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
         }
         implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
             because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should made reformat code.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this at the end to my build.graddle (Module:app) solved it:

```
dependencies {
 constraints {
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
         because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
     }
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
         because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
     }
 }
```

Comment: but you cant give me explanation why this code can fix the problem ?

Comment: If project dependencies contains org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib version 1.8.0 or greater Kotlin Gradle Plugin will now add a dependency substitution rule that will replace all other org.jebrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 or org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 dependencies with org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib to avoid classpath duplicates from different stdlib versions. [jetbrains source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the same class used in two or more dependencies that you have added. Android Studio doesn’t know which class to use when running the app. So, the error is thrown. In your case, the class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt  is used in two different Kotlin versions. To solve it:

```
apply plugin: 'com.package.domain'

android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    configurations {
        all { 
            exclude group: "com.package.domain", module: "YOUR_MODULE_NAME"
           
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `com.package.domain` and `YOUR_MODULE_NAME` with the respective values of the conflicting classes.

In your case, the group would be `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` and module would be `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`. This will exclude one of the Kotlin versions.

Comment: @RafaelSouza I have edited my answer with the modified group and module name. Pls check.

Comment: Using this code still gives the same error I'm using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1. Thanks for the feedback @Dinux